# htaccess: RewriteCond matched what is in tester unmatched

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have another problem about mod_rewrite. If user wants image (.png, .jpe?g, .gif at end of uri) then redirect to index1.html, otherwise index2.html. Tester (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) doesn't match uri without .png,jpe?g,.gif as within what is correct, but my localhost does and that is the problem.

Corrent example:
Input:

```
localhost/image.png
```

Output

```
localhost/index1.html
```

Input:

```
localhost/image
```

Output

```
localhost/index2.html
```

But what my localhost really do:
Input:

```
localhost/image.png
```

Output

```
localhost/index2.html
```

Input:

```
localhost/image
```

Output

```
localhost/index2.html
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(.png|.jpe?g|.gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(.png|.jpe?g|.gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.html
```

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!.*?\.png|.*?\.jpe?g|.*?\.gif)^(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?=.*?\.png|.*?\.jpe?g|.*?\.gif)^(.*?)(.png|.jpe?g|.gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.html
```

Try this.Added a lookahead.Postive for .png and negative for no .png .

Comment: Thanks. But again the same situation - in tester works but in localhost not. Always redirect to index2.html. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're ridiculously abusing `RewriteCond`. Simplify it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (\.png|\.jpe?g|\.gif)$ index2.html [L,R=303]
RewriteRule !^index[12]\.html$ index1.html [L,R=303]
```

The `[L]` modifier ('Last') ensures no further rules are processed, eliminating the need for a check in the second rule. The `[R=303]` makes it a 303 (See Other) redirect - alter the HTTP status code if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Again not working on localhost and still redirect into index1.html. Maybe something is wrong with my localhost?

Comment: OK, I will test it on another hosting.

Comment: Just realized you may be experiencing recursion (monitor this with your network tab in browser open!). Edited it to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule \.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ index1.html [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule !^(index[12]\.html|[^.]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ index2.html [L,NC,R]
```